# How do you get an Elastic Beanstalk website to work to be accessible via a .work extension from Hover via Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get the website I've set up in Elastic Beanstalk live. I bought a domain www.semiflex.work from Hover.com. I understand that I need to connect my domain to Elastic Beanstalk via Route 53, but I'm getting a lot of conflicting information as to how I can do this.

I've tried creating CNAME record sets in both Route 53 and Hover as an Alias with a link to my Elastic Beanstalk website, but that didn't work. I then also replaced the nameservers in Hover with the ones in Route 53, but that didn't work either. It's been roughly 4 days and I can't get my site to run on my new domain. How would I go about getting this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up solving this the old fashioned way.

**AWS part**

On Route 53, create a hosted zone. In that hosted zone, create a record set that is Type A - IPv4 - address, Alias Target = your elastic beanstalk url. Save record set. Then click on that record set, and then click on the button "Test Record Set." Then click "Get Response." Copy the I.P address "in Response returned by Route 53"

**Hover part**

Set Nameservers on hover = ns1.hover.com, ns2.hover.com. Then click on "DNS" and add two records where Type = A, Host = *, Value = your Route 53 I.P address & Type = A, Host = @, Value = your Route 53 I.P address.

Can take up to 48 hours to work, but it works!

Comment: Heads up that this solution could potentially result in your EB application becoming unreachable if the AWS provided IP address changes. Use Route53 and aliases to avoid this situation.

Comment: I.P. hasn't changed so far. Also using alias's and Route 53 didn't work.

Comment: The IP didn’t change today, but it may in the future. If you follow my instructions in the answer above Route53 will be managing your DNS zone file, and then if you set your Aliases correctly it will work.

Comment: My I.P. still hasn't changed and my site is still working

Answer (score 3):

Using Route53 to manage your DNS is simple and straightforward.

Go to to Route53 and create a hosted zone for your domain. As soon as you create your hosted zone, Route53 will generate two default entries: a SOA entry, and an NS entry with 4 nameservers that you assign to your domain in order for Route53 to manage your zone file.

Next go to your domain registrar, in this case Hover, and update the nameservers of your domain to the nameservers provided by Route53.

Now that Route53 is managing the zone file for your domain, you can create an appropriate entry for your ElasticBeanstalk app. Open your domains hosted zone and select “create record set”. On the right hand side, you’ll be able to enter a sub-domain (optionally), like www, next you’ll be able to select the type of record this is, such a an A, CNAME, MX, TXT or other. If you’re using your domain with another AWS service like Elastic Beanstalk, CloudFront, or S3, you’ll want to leave the type as an A record and then in the next section you’ll set Alias to yes. Now, in the target, you’ll either select where you want Route53 to Alias to from the available option in the current account, or if you’re aliasing to a supported service in another account you’ll enter the target such as the ElasticBeanstalk or CloudFront URL.

Click “save record set” and the entry will be live within seconds (assuming the DNS has propagated).

Now that Route53 is managing your DNS, and because IP addresses for services can change, your DNS will not need to be updated because Route53 will automatically take care of updating the destination for the record if/when it changes.

Comment: This was the most helpful resource I could find on the matter, thanks so much for sharing! I think some of the buttons have changed slightly since (e.g. "Create record" vs "Create record set") but still very easy to follow.

Answer (score -1):

We went through your issue and noticed that you must have misconfigured your route53 settings.
 You do not need to create an CNAME record for routing your domain through elastic beanstalk environment. 
Just need to create a record set by enabling Alias and selecting Alias target as your environment URL in the dropdown list.

To do so go through 
-->> Create Record set 
-->>Click on Alias 
-->>Select Alias Target.

This will resolve your problem assuming that you have updated name servers in domain registrar.

Comment: Do I leave Type as A- IPv4 address? Also what about adding a CNAME in Hover?

Comment: Yes, leave Type as  A- IPv4 address.  About updating CNAME in Hover, no need to create a CNAME record, the only thing you need to do in  Hover is an updating Nameservers.

Comment: Okay is it just the 4 nameservers that are Type NS that need to be pasted into hover? No need to paste in the SOA one? Also I've deleted all the DNS records in Hover.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only update Nameservers and there is no need to provide SOA in hover. About deleting  DNS records in Hover, all your DNS  records are managed by route53 and changes need to be done in route53 and not in Hover.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So I've added the Record you specified (Type A - IPv4 - address, Alias Target = my elastic beanstalk url. Are there any other records I need to make?

Comment: It's done. Browse the domain, you are supposed to see your site running confirming that your beanstalk environment is working properly.

Comment: No my domain still isn't pulling through the Elastic Beanstalk instance

Comment: try by browsing your environment URL, if it won't work then the problem might be in your environment and not in route53 as with above steps it was supposed to work

Comment: The environment url works fine. Should I try deleting the current nameservers and making new ones?

Comment: deleting the name servers and making new ones doesn't sound good but, try by executing it, maybe it may resolve the issue

Comment: Okay after deleting and making new name servers 2 days ago it's still not working. Are you sure I don't have to add the I.P. I get in Route 43 into the DNS settings in Hover or anything?